Syncing audio without frame dropping
I am working on an animation and want to add audio to it, however it seems the only way to get the audio to sync up correctly is to change from playing every frame to frame dropping via sync to audio. While the audio works correctly under this option, my animation looks worse with the frame dropping. Is there a way to get audio to sync up correctly without having to resort to frame dropping?

Well, optimize your scene, so that Blender is able to draw more frames in a second.

That's pretty much it. Blender will drop frames it can't render in time for the audio, so either you play every frame but it will not play audio correctly, or you drop frames, or you make it so that your scene can playback at the right frame rate without significant frame dropping.
